# JS open file from blob

Tags: javascript, ms-word, blob

I have a JavaScript method that asynchronously accepts a blob of an ms-word document. How can I open this as a word doc? I've tried:

```
function openDocAsync(blob) {
    var wblob = new Blob([blob], { type: "application/msword" });
    var status = navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(wblob);
}
```

I've also tried using:

```
var bb = new MSBlobBuilder();
bb.append(blob);
var nblob = bb.getBlob();
```

Neither to any avail. With the first option, msSaveOrOpenBlob, I can get Word to open a file of gibberish (base 64 encode of the binary), but not the desired contents.

How can I create a new Word doc using the blob supplied?

Thanks in advance